# Conditional Format Header Cell *IF* Filter Active

Tags: excel, filter, conditional-formatting

[image]

Well, I'm stumped!?!?! This fix has gotta be a simple one, but it escapes me.

I want to change the format of the **Header** cell of a filter **IF** the filter is **active/filtering**.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Searched this site and others but nada.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I developed consist of the VBA-coded user-defined function IsFiltered, the formula and conditional formatting.
[image]
First, add a module with the code:

```
Public Function IsFiltered(Ref As Range) As Variant
  Dim i As Integer, av As Variant, cnt As Integer
  With Ref.Worksheet.AutoFilter.Filters(Ref.Column _
      - Ref.Worksheet.AutoFilter.Range.Column + 1)
    On Error GoTo NoFilterHndlr
    cnt = .Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    IsFiltered = Ref.Cells(1)
  End With
  Exit Function
NoFilterCode:
  On Error GoTo 0
  IsFiltered = ""
  Exit Function
NoFilterHndlr:
  Resume NoFilterCode
End Function
```

Second, fill [C8:E8] with formula

```
=IsFiltered(C9:C40)
```

where replace "C9:C40" by the range of the column with data starting from the header row.

Third, set conditional formatting to header cells to "Highlight Cells Rules --> Equal To" and enter formula "=C$8" considering C9 is the active cell.

You can hide 8th row if need.

All references above are for data in cells as depicted. Enter references according to your data location.

Done.

[image]